# Re-map remove current line shortcut in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I would like to re-map the "remove current line" shortcut (Ctrl+L) in Notepad++ to be the same as Visual Studio (Ctrl+X), but I can't find an entry for it in the Shortcut mapper. Is this possible?

Reason: I want my right hand free for the numeric keypad, Ctrl+L is too long a stretch for my left hand.

I can't even find a menu item corresponding to remove current line, which might explain why it's not in the mapper. Seems a bit of an ooversight as this is a very common function.

I am using v8.6.2 (also checked earlier versions and seems to be missing there too).